# Creating Scientific Calculator using applet in Java

Tags: java, applet, calculator

For our midterms exam, we're supposed to create a scientific calculator that functions like one. I went to YouTube and Google to find any solutions because my professor wasn't able to teach us how to make the scientific calculator work. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class publiccalculator extends Applet implements ActionListener{

Label lblcasio = new Label("CASIO");
Label lblfx = new Label("fx-8265 PLUS");
Label lblnatural = new Label("NATURAL - V.P.A.M");

TextField txtfield1 = new TextField(30);

Button abs = new Button("Abs");
Button X2 = new Button("X^2");
Button X3 = new Button("X^3");
Button log = new Button("log");
Button sqrt = new Button("/---");

Button sin = new Button("sin");
Button cos = new Button("cos");
Button tan = new Button("tan");
Button pie = new Button("π");
Button E = new Button("E");

Button seven = new Button("7");
Button eight = new Button("8");
Button nine = new Button("9");
Button DEL = new Button("DEL");
Button AC = new Button("AC/CLEAR");

Button four = new Button("4");
Button five = new Button("5");
Button six = new Button("6");
Button multiply = new Button("X");
Button subtract = new Button("-");

Button one = new Button("1");
Button two = new Button("2");
Button three = new Button("3");
Button plus = new Button("+");
Button dive = new Button("/");

Button zero = new Button("0");
Button equals = new Button("=");
Button dot = new Button(".");
Button round = new Button("RND");


public void init(){

    setLayout(null);
    resize(500,400);

    Font myCasio= new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,18);
    Font myFX= new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,18);
    Font myNatural = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,15);


    lblcasio.setFont(myCasio);
    lblfx.setFont(myFX);
    lblnatural.setFont(myNatural);

    add(lblcasio);
    add(lblfx);
    add(lblnatural);

    add(txtfield1);

    add(abs);
    add(X2);
    add(X3);
    add(log);
    add(sqrt);

    add(sin);
    add(cos);
    add(tan);
    add(pie);
    add(E);

    add(seven);
    add(eight);
    add(nine);
    add(DEL);
    add(AC);

    add(four);
    add(five);
    add(six);
    add(multiply);
    add(subtract);

    add(one);
    add(two);
    add(three);
    add(plus);
    add(dive);

    add(zero);
    add(equals);
    add(dot);
    add(round);

    lblcasio.setBounds(60,0,100,20);
    lblfx.setBounds(350,0,150,20);
    lblnatural.setBounds(160,25,200,20);
    txtfield1.setBounds(100,50,240,20);

    abs.setBounds(100,75,35,35);
    X2.setBounds(150,75,35,35);
    X3.setBounds(200,75,35,35);
    log.setBounds(250,75,35,35);
    sqrt.setBounds(300,75,35,35);

    sin.setBounds(100,120,35,35);
    cos.setBounds(150,120,35,35);
    tan.setBounds(200,120,35,35);
    pie.setBounds(250,120,35,35);
    E.setBounds(300,120,35,35);

    seven.setBounds(100,165,35,35);
    eight.setBounds(150,165,35,35);
    nine.setBounds(200,165,35,35);
    AC.setBounds(250,165,85,35);

    four.setBounds(100,210,35,35);
    five.setBounds(150,210,35,35);
    six.setBounds(200,210,35,35);
    multiply.setBounds(250,210,35,35);
    subtract.setBounds(300,210,35,35);

    one.setBounds(100,255,35,35);
    two.setBounds(150,255,35,35);
    three.setBounds(200,255,35,35);
    plus.setBounds(250,255,35,35);
    dive.setBounds(300,255,35,35);

    zero.setBounds(100,300,35,35);
    equals.setBounds(150,300,85,35);
    dot.setBounds(250,300,35,35);
    round.setBounds(300,300,35,35);



    equals.addActionListener(this);
    one.addActionListener(this);
    two.addActionListener(this);
    three.addActionListener(this);
    plus.addActionListener(this);
    dive.addActionListener(this);
    four.addActionListener(this);
    five.addActionListener(this);
    six.addActionListener(this);
    multiply.addActionListener(this);
    subtract.addActionListener(this);
    seven.addActionListener(this);
    eight.addActionListener(this);
    nine.addActionListener(this);
    sin.addActionListener(this);
    cos.addActionListener(this);
    tan.addActionListener(this);
    pie.addActionListener(this);
    E.addActionListener(this);
    abs.addActionListener(this);
    X2.addActionListener(this);
    X3.addActionListener(this);
    log.addActionListener(this);
    sqrt.addActionListener(this);
    zero.addActionListener(this);
    dot.addActionListener(this);
    round.addActionListener(this);
    txtfield1.setEnabled(false);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
    if(e.getSource()==one){ 
        txtfield1.setText(one.getActionCommand());
    }
        else if(e.getSource()==two){
            txtfield1.setText(two.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==two){
            txtfield1.setText(two.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==three){
            txtfield1.setText(three.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==four){
            txtfield1.setText(four.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==five){
            txtfield1.setText(five.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==six){
            txtfield1.setText(six.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==seven){
            txtfield1.setText(seven.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==eight){
            txtfield1.setText(eight.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==nine){
            txtfield1.setText(nine.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==plus){
            txtfield1.setText(plus.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==subtract){
            txtfield1.setText(subtract.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==multiply){
            txtfield1.setText(multiply.getActionCommand());
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==dive){
            txtfield1.setText(dive.getActionCommand()); 
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to do the calculations and this is only the design. In addition to this, I cannot enter the numbers continuously.

Comment: ...and what is your question?  By the way, Applet is a deprecated technology, so hopefully the professor will move away from it this decade.

Comment: We're moving onto JFrame for finals :). I want to be able to do 1 + 1 = 2 or sqrt of 64 would equal to 8. Or if I do -8 abs it would equal to 8. He didn't teach us the syntax for any of those...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following URL, the example for calculator has been given using JFrame..

http://forgetcode.com/Java/216-scientific-calculator

Comment: aww it has to be in Applet and my professor said I cannot use JFrame

Comment: Check : 
http://electrofriends.com/source-codes/software-programs/java/applet-programs/java-applet-program-for-calculator/

Comment: OMG thank you so much!! It doesn't have everything I need but maybe I can learn the codes from this! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Actually you are using somewhat outdated technology so unable to help you much on that front. 
But you can definitely tell your mentor to migrate on some trending technology so as to get things easily available while preparing something! :)